# SegmentFault After upgrade glibc2.29 in CentOS7 [ec2]

Tags: linux, vim, glibc, youcompleteme

after make & install : /opt/glibc2.29

$ export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/glibc2.29/lib/libc-2.29.so

$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc2.29/lib

Segment Fault occurs when a command is executed within the /opt/glibc2.29/lib folder, or when most commands are executed after setting environment variables.

[ except : cd, pwd ... ]

**OUTPUT**

> $ ls [1] :
> 19749 segmentation fault  ls --color=tty

> $ pwd :
> /opt/glibc2.29/lib

> $ vim :
> [1]    19888 segmentation fault  vim

Environment variables can be removed within ~/.zshrc or resolved through the unset command,
but certain binaries in vim's youcompleteeme require glibc2.29.

Would you suggest me some solution or cause?